# How to sort google sheets by value of text field of a column?

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets

I have a bunch of google sheets I need to sort. All sheets need to be sorted by only one column: Priority. That column has values High, Medium and Low, and I need to sort it to be in exactly that order.
I didn't find any solution or similar question, all examples are for sorting in ascending and descending order which I know how to do, but I need High, Medium, Low order. (A-Z sorting gives High, Low, Medium order).
Any help is appreciated.

Comment: *I didn't find any solution or similar question* [Really?](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bgoogle-apps-script%5D+custom+sort)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is no simple way to do this, but what I would do would be to replace every instance of the word High with 1, Medium with 0 and Low with -1.

Then use a custom formatting rule to make those values (1,0,-1) *appear* as the words "High", "Medium" and "Low"

Then sorting (Z->A) will happen normally based on the underlying values.

Comment: Good idea, this could work with find&replace. For this case I have another column named Effort with same values, so I will have to update every field in Priority manually with 1,0,-1. Thanks a lot for the answer!

Comment: I will add another column that represents Priority with -1,0,1 and sort it